# Disable Ubuntu MATE Window List Preview

Tags: 16.04, compiz, mate, ubuntu-mate

I just installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04, and I've noticed that when I hover my cursor over a window button in the window list at the bottom of the screen, a little preview of the window will appear. I'd like to get rid of that preview, if at all possible.

I've noticed that this preview only appears when I'm using Compiz, but I cannot find any option to disable the preview anywhere in the CompizConfig Settings Manager, MATE Tweak, or the applet settings itself. I'm completely stumped here. How do I get rid of this window preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's there in CompizConfig settings manager (Which you'll need to install if you havn't already, using `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`)

It's under "Extras", uncheck "Thumbnail window previews", and that should turn them off:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the section "Extras" is missing [after installing `compizconfig-settings-manager`](https://askubuntu.com/a/781701/717970), install also `compiz-plugins-extra`:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

PS: I would have preferred to add this as a comment to the linked answer, but I'm missing the 50+ reputation... ;-)